# Angular-Material: What is md-tile-left and md-tile-content

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am reading the [example for md-list](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.list) (and md-item) on the Angular-Material-site. In the source I see this html:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <md-content>
    <md-list>
      <md-item ng-repeat="item in todos">
        <md-item-content>
          <div class="md-tile-left">
              <img ng-src="{{item.face}}" class="face" alt="{{item.who}}">
          </div>
          <div class="md-tile-content">
            <h3>{{item.what}}</h3>
            <h4>{{item.who}}</h4>
            <p>
              {{item.notes}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </md-item-content>
      </md-item>
    </md-list>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

But I do not see what is md-tile-left and md-tile-content, I cannot find these anywhere in the docs or in the CSS of the source code of the list-example. Where can I find info on these classes are and do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inspecting the sources I found the classes in docs.css

> /**  * The left tile for a list item.  */

```
.md-tile-left {
  min-width: 56px;
  margin-right: -16px; }
```

> /**  * The center content tile for a list item.  */

```
.md-tile-content {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  padding: 16px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; }
  .md-tile-content h3 {
    margin: 0 0 3px 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.1em; }
  .md-tile-content h4 {
    margin: 0 0 3px 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.9em; }
  .md-tile-content p {
    margin: 0 0 3px 0;
    font-size: 0.75em; }
```

See - [List css file on github](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/9a122398d0757f1a6d089f05c7e31d1e9331bf7c/src/components/list/list.scss)

Comment: Aha. Ok. Was hoping there was a some kind of "normal" documentation on this somewhere... Thanks for the help!